# Coding error detected, it must be fixed by a programmer: Invalid ->cf for profile condition

Tags: php, moodle

I am getting an error while i am trying to restore a course backup. Can anyone help me out. Error i am getting is bellow.

```
Coding error detected, it must be fixed by a programmer: Invalid ->cf for profile condition
More information about this error
Debug info: 
Error code: codingerror
Stack trace:
o   line 120 of /availability/condition/profile/classes/condition.php: coding_exception thrown
o   line 234 of /availability/classes/tree.php: call to availability_profile\condition->__construct()
o   line 144 of /availability/classes/info.php: call to core_availability\tree->__construct()
o   line 114 of /availability/classes/info.php: call to core_availability\info->decode_availability()
o   line 318 of /availability/classes/info.php: call to core_availability\info->get_availability_tree()
o   line 823 of /backup/moodle2/restore_stepslib.php: call to core_availability\info->update_after_restore()
o   line 34 of /backup/util/plan/restore_execution_step.class.php: call to restore_update_availability->define_execution()
o   line 181 of /backup/util/plan/base_task.class.php: call to restore_execution_step->execute()
o   line 177 of /backup/util/plan/base_plan.class.php: call to base_task->execute()
o   line 167 of /backup/util/plan/restore_plan.class.php: call to base_plan->execute()
o   line 333 of /backup/controller/restore_controller.class.php: call to restore_plan->execute()
o   line 224 of /backup/util/ui/restore_ui.class.php: call to restore_controller->execute_plan()
o   line 111 of /backup/restore.php: call to restore_ui->execute()
```

Can anyone know about how to fix this error.

Comment: Has the backup been created in a different version of moodle?

Comment: @JonasKöritz :Yes backup is created on 2.6.2 and we are trying to restore on 3.0.

Comment: This could be Impossible. Have you read the documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error : `/availability/condition/profile/classes/condition.php`

I'm guessing there is custom profile field missing.

Look in site admin -> users -> accounts -> user profile fields

Does the list of fields match on both the old system and the new system?

Answer (score 1):

Backups of different moodle versions and moodle instances/systems could not be 100% compatible.
Try to restore the backup in the same moodle version, then update moodle to your current version, backup and restore into your production environment from the updated moodle system.